# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I am enjoying it. While working on a project I got this error: ErrorException in helpers.php

the view:

```
<div class="form-group">


<div class="input-group">


  <div class="input-group-addon"> Name</div>
  {!!      Form::text('name',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Project Name'])      !!}

 </div>
```

```
  <div class="form-group">


      <div class="input-group">


        <div class="input-group-addon">Desc</div>
          {!!      Form::textarea('desc',['rows'=>'3','cols'=>'3'  , 
        'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'description'])      !!}

     </div>


</div>
```

Comment: So, what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @SHOSHA K  try this  `{!!      Form::text('name','',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Project Name'])      !!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second value for textarea() and text() must be a default value, try this:

```
Form::textarea('desc', '', ['rows'=>'3'

Form::text('name', '', ['class'=>'form-control'
```

Answer (score 0):

Second Parameter must be a default value, best practice set that value in null, than if field data do not pass through validation, the enter value do not disappear.

```
{{ Form::text('first_name', null, array('class' => 'field')) }}
```

More information about [text input field](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/155/creating-a-text-input-field)

```
{{ Form::textarea('notes', null, ['size' => '3x3']) }}
```

More information about [textarea input field](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/162/creating-a-textarea-input-field)